# Submit worker functions in dask distributed without waiting for the functions to end

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, apscheduler

I have this python code that uses the `apscheduler` library to submit processes, it works fine:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
array = [ 1, 3, 5, 7]

for elem in array:
    scheduler.add_job(function_to_submit, kwargs={ 'elem': elem })

scheduler.start()


def function_to_submit(elem):
     print(str(elem))
```

Note that the processes are submitted in parallel, and that the code does NOT wait for the processes to end.

What I need is to migrate this code to `dask distributed` to use workers. The problem that I have is that if I use `dask` submit method the code waits until all the functions end, and I need the code to continue. How to achieve that?

```
   client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')
   future1 = client.submit(function_to_submit, 1)
   future3 = client.submit(function_to_submit, 3)
   L = [future1, future3]
   client.gather(L)  # <-- this waits until all the futures end
```

Comment: client.gather blocks until they're all complete. you don't have to call it... what are you trying to do with the futures?

Comment: I just want to submit processes in different workers

Comment: right - I'm just saying you don't have to call client.gather. so it depends on what you want to happen *next*

Comment: Got it. Nothing should happen next, the main process will start/submit the tasks in the clients, and then end

Comment: ohhhh ok. you're looking to allow the python process calling the tasks to die. got it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dask distributed has a [`fire_and_forget`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/futures.html#distributed.fire_and_forget) method which is an alternative to e.g. [`client.compute`](http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#distributed.Client.compute) or [`dask.distributed.wait`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/futures.html#distributed.wait) if you want the *scheduler* to hang on to the tasks even if the futures have fallen out of scope on the python process which submitted them.

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, fire_and_forget
client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')
fire_and_forget(client.submit(function_to_submit, 1))
fire_and_forget(client.submit(function_to_submit, 3))

# your script can now end and the scheduler will
# continue executing these until they end or the
# scheduler is terminated
```

See the [dask.distributed docs on Futures](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/futures.html#fire-and-forget) for examples and other usage patterns.